# Plot after mean()

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a table after a groupby and mean command. But after the mean() the header is not in the right order and it can't plot anymore.

```
sl1 = pd.read_csv("sealevel.csv")
sl1['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(sl1['Time'])
s = sl1.groupby(sl1.Time.dt.year).mean()

plt.plot(s['Time'], s['GMSL'])
plt.xlabel("Year")
plt.ylabel("Sea Level rise in mm")
plt.title("Sea Level rise between 1992 and 2016")
plt.show()
```

[image: error message]

Comment: yeah, you lose the `Time ` field when you do the `groupby`. Look at Scott's answer, he's correct (don't forget to upvote and accept the answer!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, using pandas plot:

```
ax = sl1.groupby(sl1.Time.dt.year).mean().plot()
ax.set_title('Sea Level rise between 1992 and 2016')
ax.set_xlabel('Year')
ax.set_ylabel('Sea Level rise in mm')
```

Comment: I get this error: ' PlotAccessor' object has no attribute 'set_title'

Comment: @Woody Be sure to include the parenthesis after plot.  "...plot()"

Answer (score 1):

Without checking any toy data I'm pretty sure it is because when you do a groupby like this, the column by which you are grouping will become the new index. You need to call reset_index() which will push time back into the columns.

Comment: Check the examples section here. You can see that the groupby category becomes the new index. 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Comment: And see documentation here for how reset_index() works: 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html

Comment: It moved the columns back together but it will only give me the GMSL as column when i try to read the columns

Comment: @WmH I was having a hard time understanding the purpose of reset_index(), your answer cleared that up for me, thanks